# Importing sources from another MS Word document

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, bibliography

I've been collaborating with another person who sent me a Word document that I need to merge with mine. He has several citations and a bibliography in the end, and so do I.

Is there a way to cleanly import his sources into my master list so I could merge the bibliography in the resulting document other than doing it manually? He left for a vacation and did not send an exported file of the sources